# Can I pull data from one MS Access Database and Put it into Another?

Tags: ms-access

I'm not a strong programmer but I have been getting by in VBA.
I'm trying MS Access to create some tools for work.
In my job I have two access databases that I use regularly- one which I pull data from and one which I put the data into.  Is it possible to make an 'umbrella' access program which will help me automate the process?

For an example I open access database 1 and it tells me to release data 'A'.  I go release the data and I have to let access database 2 know that I have done this.  Could I create a 3rd access database which pulls from 1 and fills out the form for 2?

Thanks for the help!

Nick

Comment: Yes. As for how: that's too broad. Read into linked tables.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the tip. I was searching "can I use a MS access database to control another" and wasn't finding much...  Knowing that its called linked tables is a big help.

Comment: Depending on how complicated the Access databases are you can probably even just copy paste all elements from one into another and have a single file.